# Вставка комментариев в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

Мне нужно, чтобы комментарии находились внутри

```
<div id="blog-wrap" >
  <section class="container page-content" >
    <section class="col-md-8 omega ">
```

Но, когда я их вставил перед закрывающим тегом, как видно из кода ниже, они почему-то выводятся на странице за этими классами, а не внутри них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы комментарии находились внутри этих тегов?

```
         <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="blog-wrap" >
            <section class="container page-content" >
              <hr class="vertical-space2">
              <section class="col-md-8 omega ">  

                <article class="blog-single-post">
               <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
               <p>
           <?php the_content(); ?>

           </p>

            <?php
                            $posttags = get_the_tags();
                            if ($posttags) { 
                                ?>
                           <span class="label label-warning">Метки статьи</span>
                            <div class="meta"><i class="icon-tags"></i>
                              <?php  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                $tag_links[] = '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
                                }
                                 echo join( ', ', $tag_links );
                                 echo "</div>";
                            }
                            ?>

                            </div>


                     <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts were found.' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

                </article>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
                   </section> 
                   </section>
            </div>
```

Comment: У вас лишний /div. Посчитайте открывающие и закрывающие. Привычка к аккуратному форматированию кода избавит от таких ошибок.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я перепроверил только что количество открывающих и закрывающих тегов, количество одинаковое, все равно не работает.